# "Connect timeout on endpoint URL" when running cron job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have set a crontab file to run a Python script that creates an JSON file and writes it to an S3 bucket.  It runs as expected when executed from the command line, but when I run it as a cron job, I get the following error:

> botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL

This results from the following lines of code in the script:

```
import boto3

def main():
    # Create EC2 client and get EC2 response
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = ec2.describe_instances()
```

My guess is that some permission is not set in the cron job, denying me access to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had to set the proxy settings so I access AWS as myself rather than root.  I ran the cron job as a Linux shell script rather then a Python script, and exported my http_proxy, https_proxy, and no_proxy settings found in ~/.bash_profile in the first lines of the shell script

```
`export http_proxy=<http_proxy from ~/.bash_profile>
 export https_proxy=<https_proxy from ~/.bash_profile>
 export no_proxy=<no_proxy from ~./bash_profile>
 python <python script>`
```